# Elasticsearch find ONLY perfect match

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been trying to do this for some time, read and searched a lot and I haven't found any definitive answer or solution.

Let's say we add some documents:

```
$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/1 -d '{"item": "foo" }'
{"_index":"tm","_type":"entries","_id":"1","_version":1,"created":true}

$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/2 -d '{"item": "foo bar" }'
{"_index":"tm","_type":"entries","_id":"2","_version":1,"created":true}

$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/3 -d '{"item": "foo bar foo" }'
{"_index":"tm","_type":"entries","_id":"3","_version":1,"created":true}
```

After this, i want to find ONLY the document(s) that match perfectly the search query

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search?q=foo
```

The result contains all 3 documents and I only want to get the one which matches "foo" only and nothing else.

Also,

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search?q=bar foo
```

Should not return any results.

1. Can Elasticsearch do that?
2. How?

Update: 
Existing mapping:

```
{
    "tm": {
        "mappings": {
            "entries": {
                "properties": {
                    "item": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide your mapping..!

Comment: done. I tried changing the mapping (following this example http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/) but search didn't work after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use he following Mapping.

```
{
"tm": {
    "mappings": {
        "entries": {
            "properties": {
                "item": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And use term query to find exact match. Term queries are not analyzed.[refer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query)

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/_search" -d'
{
"query": {
   "term": {
      "item": {
         "value": "foo bar"
      }
   }
  }
 }'
```

Comment: This appear to be working. Took me some time to set the mapping. Working with mappings in elasticsearch is a bitch. Thank you.

Comment: hi again. any idea why this returns only one result even if i have two identical documents?

Comment: Can you provide the sample documents ?

Comment: Made a new test and this time it worked. http://pastie.org/private/i93k2uw4rniwlaw48le2g pretty weird. In my current set of data: http://pastie.org/private/ueajwtokks1tmymwni9ag i have 3 documents with "striped":"email" and the search only returns the ones that have distingt values for other fields.

Comment: there is a space in there "email ". jesus christ. sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"index" : "not_analyzed"` in the mapping.

And query should be something like

```
{
  "match_phrase": {
    "item": "foo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use match query instead of query_string. It'll solve your issue.

```
{
    "match" : {
        "item" : "bar foo"
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html):

Also, make sure the terms you are searching is actually present in the indexed field. For that you need to use analyser "keyword".For more information take a look at [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html).

Thanks

Comment: tried that. $ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/_search -d '{"query": { "match": {"item": "foo"}}}' returns 3 results.

Comment: Change your analyzer to keyword. Right now you are using default analyzer which is standard one.

Comment: i'll try that, as soon as i figure out how to edit the mapping of an index, 10x

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search from GET request, I think this might help:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/_search?q=item:foo
```

so it is of syntax, `_search?q= <field>:<value>`

You can find documentation here, [URI Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)

And, If you are trying to have filter, it is good to have mapping with not_analyzed (as described above).

And for complex queries,

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/tm/entries/_search" -d'
{
    "filter": {
        "term": {
           "item": "foo"
        }
    }
}'
```

hope this helps.

Comment: What is the response?